# aftersave() and beforesave() with dirty attributes

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new Yii2. I'm stuck in a point of triggering changed attributes in update. I just need to get changed attributes and save another table record is changed to new value.

Please any one could help me to solve this with before save, after save and dirty attributes?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem

Comment: i want to update product details. when updating that i need to save changed value with previous value in another table with class name and table id. I thought i can do this with before save and dirty attributes. But i'm not clear how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the getAttributes() and getOldAttributes methods in yii\db\ActiveRecord. 
ie:

```
public actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $changed_attributes = array_diff_assoc($model->getOldAttributes(), $model->getAttributes());
        if($model->save()) {
            //Save changed values in other table
           //$changed_attributes contains attribute_name=>value pairs of changed(old) attributes. and $model contains new values. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also use: `$model->getDirtyAttributes()` to get attribute=>value pairs for all changed values.

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord model:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changeAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changeAttributes);

    // $changeAttributes
}
```

Comment: is this cahngeAttributes and dirtyAttributes are same?